# Restricting intervals for parameter equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

What interval $I$ should we restrict the parameter t, when the graph of parametric equations $\begin{align*} x=t+1, y=2t^2 +1 \end{align*}$ for $t\in I$ is identical to the graph of the parametric equations $\begin{align*} x=1+\sin s,y=2-\cos(2s) \end{align*}$ for $s\in[0,\pi)$?

To solve this, would I set the $x's$ equal and the $y's$ equal? I.e.: $1+ \sin s = t+1 , 2-\cos (2s) = 2t^2+1$?

Answer (score 1):

I would've approached it in different way:

Let's say those graphs are identical, which means their $x$ and $y$ values are identical along the way:

For x-axis:

$t+1 = 1+ sin(s)$

$t = sin(s) ... (1)$

For y-axis:

$2t^2+1 = 2-cos(2s)$

$2t^2 = 1-(cos^2(s)-sin^2(s))$

$2t^2 = 1-(1-2sin^2(s))$

$2t^2 = 2sin^2(s)$

$t=sin(s) ... (2)$

Both x-axis and y-axis analysis led to the same relation $t=sin(s)$, knowing that $s \in[0,\pi)$ will give me $t\in[0,1]$

Answer (score 0):

The curvev is a parabola $y=2x^²-4x+3$

$$2t^2+1=2(t+1)^2-4(t+1)+3$$

And 
$$2−\cos(2s)=2(1+\sin(s))^2-4(1+\sin(s))+3$$

Comment: Simplifying both gives me: $2t^2+4t+2 -4t-4+3 = 2t^2 + 1$ and $2(1+2sin(s) +sin^2 s) -4-4sin(s) + 3 = 2+4sin(s) + 2sin^2 (s) -4 -4sin(s) + 3 = 2sin^2 (s) -2 = 0  --> sin^2 - 1 = 0 --> sin^2(s) = 1$. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: That means that $s = \frac{\pi}{6}$. And $2t^2+1 = 0 = t^2 = -1/2 = t = +/- i/\sqrt{2}$. Is that right?

Comment: $\cos(2s)=1-2\sin^2s$

Comment: cos(2s) = 1/2?????

Comment: That gives me $s = \frac{\pi}{6}$ again.

Comment: If that's true, then $x=1+sin (s),y=2−cos(2s)$ will give me: $x = 3/2 , y = 1/2$?

Comment: x=t+1,y=2t2+1   3/2 = t+1 gives me t = 1/2 for x. -1/2 = 2t^2. t^2 = -1/4. t = + and - i/2? I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: I am very lost now...any tips?

Comment: Are the two parameterizations of the same curve no matter the parameter

Comment: Are you saying that both parameters have the same curve? What interval should I restrict t to? Is it $[0, 1/2]$?

Comment: Chain of parameters is $t=\sin s$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20822/discussion-between-mathy-person-and-jimbo).

Comment: What I have is that: $t = \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}}$, and $-\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}}$