# To what interval $I$ must we restrict the parameter $t$ if the graph of the parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To what interval $I$ must we restrict the parameter $t$ if the graph of the parametric equations
\begin{align*}
x&=t+1,\\
y&=2t^2 +1
\end{align*}
for $t\in I$ is identical to the graph of the parametric equations
\begin{align*}
x&=1+\sin s,\\
y&=2-\cos(2s)
\end{align*}
for $s\in[0,\pi)$?

Comment: Hint: with the second equations you cannot represent any point with $y > 3$ or $x > 2$.

Comment: You might want to tell us your thoughts and what you've done so far.

Comment: This question is already answered on this website: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132786/restricting-intervals-for-parameter-equations